# When and how does the `each` method work?

Tags: ruby

I don't understand why `each` method is defined in this code:

```
class VowelFinder
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(string)
    @string = string
  end

  def each
    @string.scan(/[aeiou]/) do |vowel|
      yield vowel
    end
  end
end

vf = VowelFinder.new("the quick brown fox jumped")
vf.inject(:+)
# => "euiooue"
```

This code works, but not without `each`. Also, If I use `Array` and `Range` classes, and overwrite the `each` method in them, something different happens.

When I create an object, and call `inject` method on it, when and how does the `each`  method work?

Comment: https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/05/29/ruby-magic-enumerable-and-enumerator.html is a pretty good explanation.

Comment: its working bro! @matt

Comment: The author has included `Enumerable` into the custom class `VowelFinder`. To be able to use the many wonderful instance methods of  `Enumerable` the class must have an instance method `each` which returns an enumerator. All of `Enumerable`'s instance methods require an enumerator as their receiver.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Just like the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) say: "The `Enumerable` mixin provides collection classes with several traversal and searching methods, and with the ability to sort. **The class must provide a method `each`, which yields successive members of the collection.**"

Comment: @muistooshort No real need to include `Enumerable` when you can just create an `Enumerator`. The `Enumerator` class already has an `each` method and includes `Enumerable`. In this case one could use `Kernel#to_enum`/`#enum_for`, such as `"the quick brown fox jumped".enum_for(:scan, /[aeiou]/).inject(:+)#=>"euiooue"`. This will create an `Enumerator` from `String#scan` with the argument `/[aeiou]/` and when inject is called each vowel will be yielded to the block provided by `Symbol#to_proc`.

Comment: @engineersmnky Yeah but this looks more like an exercise in using `Enumerable` than anything else. All academic examples are bad and full of hand waving but the underlying principle here, as I see it, is that `Enumerable` is built on `each`.

Answer (score 1):

**TL:DR** The Enumerable mixin works by a kind of contract with you. You tell it what `each` means, and it brings to life several dozen additional methods. `inject` is one of those methods.

#### Actual discussion

How does `inject` work? Roughly speaking, it walks through something that consists of *elements*, applying a function to the elements as they arrive. What are the elements of the string `"the quick brown fox jumped"`? Arguably, they are its characters. So if we treat the string as an array of characters and inject `+`, which concatenates strings, we expect to get the original string itself:

```
arr = "The quick brown fox jumped".scan /./
puts arr.inject(:+) # => the quick brown fox jumped
```

But now let's go a step further. Ruby has mixins, and in particular it has the Enumerable mixin. This allows us to treat *anything we like* as "something that has elements". So instead of an array, let's make it possible to inject `+` over the elements of the string *itself*. To do so, we must define `each` for a String, so that it becomes possible to walk the elements of the string. Once we do that, Enumerable's many methods, including `inject`, will spring to life.

What should `each` mean for a string? Again, we could simply make it mean each character. We could conceivably do that by aliasing `each` to the existing `each_char`:

```
class String
  include Enumerable
  alias each each_char
end
s = "the quick brown fox jumped"
puts s.inject(:+) # => the quick brown fox jumped
```

But instead of aliasing `each` to `each_char`, we could define `each` ourselves from scratch. We already know one way to do that, using `scan`:

```
class String
  include Enumerable
  def each
    self.scan(/./) do |ch|
      yield ch
    end
  end
end
s = "the quick brown fox jumped"
puts s.inject(:+) # => the quick brown fox jumped
```

But the definition of `each` is up to me, so instead of scanning for *every* character, I can scan for some *other* pattern! For example, I can scan for vowels instead:

```
class String
  include Enumerable
  def each
    self.scan(/[aeiou]/) do |ch|
      yield ch
    end
  end
end
s = "the quick brown fox jumped"
puts s.inject(:+) # => euiooue
```

But let's not lame String by defining `each` in this curious way. Let's sluff this whole functionality off onto a custom class. Let's call it VowelFinder! Thus we end up with the code you started with.